# Symfony 5.5 Mailer async with attachment

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, attachment, mailer

I am trying to send mail using Symfony Mailer (https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html).
I am attaching a PDF file to the mail, using
`$email->attachFromPath('media/test.pdf', 'Attachment name');`. Everything is working fine and the mail is sent (using mailtrap for testing)

The problem is that when I want to use Symfony Messenger to make the mail async, the attachment is not working. I get the error

`Symfony\Component\Mailer\Messenger\SendEmailMessage   2022-01-13 12:38:51   Path "media/test.pdf" is not readable.`

When I remove the attachment, the mail is sent (with async). But when I put the attachment, I get an error.
So now, I have to use sync transport when sending mail with attachment, but it is very slow and blocking.

I wonder why this is happening even if it is the same code for (and path) for async and sync mail.

Here is the `messenger.yaml`

```
framework:
    messenger:
        # Uncomment this (and the failed transport below) to send failed messages to this transport for later handling.
        failure_transport: failed

        transports:
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html#transport-configuration
            async: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN)%'
            failed: 'doctrine://default?queue_name=failed'
            # sync: 'sync://'

        routing:
            # Route your messages to the transports
            'Symfony\Component\Mailer\Messenger\SendEmailMessage': async
```

In .env,

```
MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN=doctrine://default
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that maybe it doesn't look at the same path for /media/test.pdf for `sync` and `async`.

So what I did is using the root path

```
$baseUrl = getcwd();
$path = $baseUrl . '/media/test.pdf';
```

and then using this path for the attachment